# Reshaping CSV data in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have csv dataset as :

```
    5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
    7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
    6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,Iris-virginica
    4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
    4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
    4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
    5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,Iris-versicolor
    5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,Iris-versicolor
    5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
    7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,Iris-virginica
    6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica
```

I want to have it as:

```
Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica
5.1,3.5,1.4,
7.0,3.2,4.7,
6.3,3.3,6.0,
4.9,3.0,1.4,
4.7,3.2,1.3
```

I searched and there are lot of answers like using pd.pivot but failed to have desired output. When I tried giving some index A to pivot, it thorw 'index has duplicate entries'.
If answer contains .pivot function, then can you please explain me what actually index, column and values are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need filter columns by positions - first 3 by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and if necessary set columns names by `list`:

```
df = df.iloc[:, :3]
df.columns = ['Iris-setosa','Iris-versicolor','Iris-virginica']
print (df)
    Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
0           5.1              3.5             1.4
1           7.0              3.2             4.7
2           6.3              3.3             6.0
3           4.9              3.0             1.4
4           4.7              3.2             1.3
5           4.4              2.9             1.4
6           5.1              2.5             3.0
7           5.7              2.8             4.1
8           5.8              2.7             5.1
9           7.1              3.0             5.9
10          6.3              2.9             5.6
```